# problem in Latex equation formula

Tags: equations

I use a double-column journal template.
The alignment of the following equation in Latex is not correct.

```
\begin{equation}
\footnotesize   
\label{eq:28}
\frac{ \partial D({R}',R^*)}{\partial {R}' } |_{{R}'=R^*}   =\frac{1}{w_i}[-\frac{f(\acute{y})}{\acute{N}} \frac{1-F(\acute{y} )^\acute{N}}{1-F(\acute{y} )}+f(\acute{y} ) F(\acute{y} )^{\acute{N}-1}- \int_{-\infty}^{\acute{y}}(1-\acute{N}) f( \epsilon )^2F( \epsilon )^{\acute{N}-2}d \epsilon]
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Can anyone help to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `^\acute{N}` that should be `^{\acute{N}}`.

But the formula will not fit anyway and `\footnotesize` is not legal inside `equation`.

Better split across lines:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:28}
\begin{split}
&\frac{\partial D({R}',R^*)}{\partial {R}' } \bigg|_{{R}'=R^*} \\
&\quad=\frac{1}{w_i}\biggl[
  -\frac{f(\acute{y})}{\acute{N}}\frac{1-F(\acute{y})^{\acute{N}}}{1-F(\acute{y})}
  +f(\acute{y}) F(\acute{y})^{\acute{N}-1}
\\
&\qquad\qquad
  -\int_{-\infty}^{\acute{y}}(1-\acute{N}) f(\epsilon )^2 F(\epsilon)^{\acute{N}-2}\,d\epsilon
\biggr]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Better yet if you also load `newtx`.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1][1-4]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:28}
\begin{split}
&\frac{\partial D({R}',R^*)}{\partial {R}' } \bigg|_{{R}'=R^*} \\
&\quad=\frac{1}{w_i}\biggl[
  -\frac{f(\acute{y})}{\acute{N}}\frac{1-F(\acute{y})^{\acute{N}}}{1-F(\acute{y})}
  +f(\acute{y}) F(\acute{y})^{\acute{N}-1}
\\
&\qquad\qquad
  -\int_{-\infty}^{\acute{y}}(1-\acute{N}) f(\epsilon )^2 F(\epsilon)^{\acute{N}-2}\,d\epsilon
\biggr]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the parenthesis between `^` and `\acute{N}`. Try with this

```
\begin{equation}
\footnotesize   
\label{eq:28}
\frac{ \partial D({R}',R^*)}{\partial {R}' } |_{{R}'=R^*}   =\frac{1}{w_i}[-\frac{f(\acute{y})}{\acute{N}} \frac{1-F(\acute{y} )^{\acute{N}}}{1-F(\acute{y} )}+f(\acute{y} ) F(\acute{y} )^{\acute{N}-1}- \int_{-\infty}^{\acute{y}}(1-\acute{N}) f( \epsilon )^2F( \epsilon )^{\acute{N}-2}d \epsilon]
\end{equation}
```